# Losing data after deployment - clarification

Tags: google-app-maker

I touched upon this in a question I submitted yesterday. I am not sure I clarified well what my issue is in that post, so, just to make it less confusing I thought I'd just create a new post.

This is what's happening.

If I go into Preview mode and create a new record and then refresh my browser, the record remains (as you can see I now have many records in Preview). But I realize the Preview is unique to my login.

[Inline image 2][1]

But when I do a deployment and go to the deployment url:

[Inline image 3][2]

And then I create and submit a new record, it works correctly and displays in my list view:

[Inline image 4][3]

[image: Inline image 5]

But then, if I just stay on the same window tab and refresh my browser, my document disappears.

[image: Inline image 6]

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permissions problem. Are you using the same account when using the deployed version as when you tested with the Preview mode? If not, the account you used for the deployed version may not have permission to view the record you just entered. When you enter the new record it will appear on the form but when you refresh your browser it does not appear.